# Ubuntu 20.04 displaylink patch for xorg

Tags: 20.04, xorg, displaylink

https://bugs.launchpad.net/xorg-server/+bug/1875015

Can anyone tell me if this problem is fixed or will be fixed soon. Currently I reload the patch supplied by Displaylink for 20.04

https://www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=67148

I have had to stop automatically applying security updates as the version of xorg that dosnt work with Displaylink will automatically get reinstalled. Should I post this on the Xorg upstream support?

Is this fixed in 20.10 or is there a work around so I can stop Ubuntu from try to apply its version of xorg rather than the patch?

I also run pop/os and this dosnt seem to be a problem in their os which I know is based on Ubuntu 20.04

Any thoughts on how else I might fix this would be helpfull.

I have found this answer as a temp fix at
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/-/issues/1028
to stop the update
#sudo apt-mark hold xserver-xorg-core

Answer (score 0):

The [DisplayLink XServer Patch](https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/file?d=310) works for me. I put xserver-xorg-core package on hold, which allows me to continue to install updates. We still need a long term solution but, this is a nice work around.

```
sudo apt-mark hold xserver-xorg-core
```